# How to decrease size of a string by using preceding numbers?

Tags: javascript

How to decrease size of a string like replace `"CCCC" to "4C"`.

If there is one letter segment, it is left unchanged; `"ABBBCCDCC" to "A3B2CD2C"`.

Comment: This sounds like a homework task. Have you written any code yet? What is your approach? What problem are you facing at implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the callback argument of `String#replace`, and a regex with a backreference (`\1`):

```js
let s = "ABBBCCDCC";
let res = s.replace(/(.)\1+/g, m => m.length + m[0]);

console.log(res);
```

In case you need a non-regex solution using the most basic JavaScript only, then you could use the following code, which just implements what you would do with pencil and paper:

```js
let s = "ABBBCCDCC";
let res = "";
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    let chr = s[i];
    let count = 1;
    while (i < s.length && s[i+1] == chr) {
        i++;
        count++;
    }
    if (count > 1) res += count;
    res += chr;
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: this is correct, but it should be m.length + m[0] instead of m[0] + m.length to match what the question required.

Comment: I think you need to switch the ordering; yours shows `B3` rather than `3B`. Easy to fix. And a clever solution.

Comment: Order changed ,-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getTransformText(element){
    let text = element.value;
    let lastMatchedChar = ''; // This help us know the last 'char' that was matched
    let result =  (text.split('').map((c, i)=>
    {
        let cCount = 0; 
        if(c !== lastMatchedChar)
            lastMatchedChar = c;
        else
            return '';
            
        let nonMatch = false;
        
        text.split('').forEach((c_1, i_1)=>
        {
          if(i <= i_1)
          {
            if(lastMatchedChar === c_1 && !nonMatch )
            {
                lastMatchedIndex = i_1;
                ++cCount
            } else {
                nonMatch = true;
            }
          }
        });
        
        return ''.concat(cCount,lastMatchedChar); 
    }));
    
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result.join('');
    
    return result.join('');
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter your string" onkeyup="return getTransformText(this)" id="in" />

<div>
Answer is: <span id="out"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function decreaseSize(example) {
    example = example.toUpperCase();
    newString = [1, example[0]]
    for (i = 1; i < example.length; i++) {
        if (example[i] === newString[newString.length - 1]) {
            if (typeof newString[newString.length - 2] === "number") {
                newString[newString.length - 2]++;
            } else if (typeof newString[newString.length - 2] === "string") {
                newString[newString.length - 1] = 2;
                newString.push(example[i]);
            }
        } else {
            newString.push(example[i])
        }
    }
    newString.shift();
    return newString.join("")
}
```

Edit:

```
function decreaseSize(example) {
    example = example.toUpperCase();
    newString = [1, example[0]]
    for (i = 1; i < example.length; i++) {
        if (example[i] === newString[newString.length - 1]) {
            if (typeof newString[newString.length - 2] === "number") {
                newString[newString.length - 2]++;
            } else if (typeof newString[newString.length - 2] === "string") {
                newString[newString.length - 1] = 2;
                newString.push(example[i]);
            }
        } else {
            newString.push(example[i])
        }
    }
    if (newString[0] === 1) {
        newString.shift();
    }
    return newString.join("")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't output the correct result. i.e `AASSSSDDDDEEECC` outputs `
A4S4D3E2C`

Comment: oh yes, the first character gets shifted, so `2` was removed, adding a simple `if` statement does the work